# Paginate rows from SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to finish writting my news/blog ASP.net C# application and I am getting stuck on how to return only 10 items at a time after filtering items based on tag or keyword.
This is an example of what I am looking for:

1. User queries sql by browsing to ?tag=Pizza
2. Backend finds all tags that equal the query string (sent over as a @ parameter).  This part I have figured out.
3. Now I want it to just return 10 rows at a time from this filtered statement.  I was easily able to do this with this when I wasn't filtering anything out:

   ```
   sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT row_number() over(ORDER BY news_id) AS row_number, * FROM news) T WHERE row_number BETWEEN (SELECT rowcnt FROM sys.sysindexes WHERE (id = OBJECT_ID('news')) AND (indid < 2))-(@start+10) AND (SELECT rowcnt FROM sys.sysindexes  WHERE (id = OBJECT_ID('news')) AND (indid < 2))-(@start) ORDER BY news_id DESC";

   sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@start", SqlDbType.Int).Value = start;
   ```
4. I then display at the bottom of the page the user the option to view more.  (This part is easy as I just need to add 10 to a query string of ?num=).

What is the best way to go about this goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Understanding how row_number numbers the results is a little tricky at first.

It looks like two things are making this more complicated than it could be.  The row_number function must be in the ***same SELECT or an outer SELECT*** than the filtering is happening, otherwise you are numbering the whole table, rather than numbering the results.  Your query numbered all the results in the table **before the rows were limited** because row_number was used in a SELECT that was **inside** the SELECT with the WHERE.

Second, it looks like you are hitting sys.indexes to get the number of rows (which I am not sure is always accurate) to the the row number range in reverse when you can just add a DESC to the row_number function.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            row_number() over(ORDER BY news_id DESC) AS row_number,
            *
        FROM
            news
        WHERE
            --user filter goes here
            news_cat = 'Pizza'
    ) AS T
WHERE
    row_number BETWEEN @start AND @start + 10
```

Comment: Aaronaught provided useful links, but hadn't understood yet that you were having trouble numbering the results properly.

Comment: Does this affect query performance? is it recommended to do it this way?

Answer (score 3):

See the following questions on SQL Server paging queries:

- [Paging SQL Server 2005 results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840/paging-sql-server-2005-results)
- [How to do pagination in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244322/how-to-do-pagination-in-sql-server-2008)
- [How to return a page of results from SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190/how-to-return-a-page-of-results-from-sql)
- [Pagination in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757575/pagination-in-sql-server)
- [What is the best way to paginate results in MS SQLServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109232/what-is-the-best-way-to-paginate-results-in-ms-sqlserver)
- [How can I do server side pagination of results in SQL Server 2000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240360/how-can-i-do-server-side-pagination-of-results-in-sql-server-2000)

And so on.

Comment: All of those are what I am already doing. They just count the rows of the entire table.  I need to be able to go from essentially row 100 to 88 to 12 to 1 or something like that.

Comment: Um, no, they don't.  All of the other questions do exactly what you're asking to do.  If your question is different from those, then you're going to have to be a lot more specific about *how* it's different.

Comment: I need to "SELECT * FROM news WHERE news_cat = 'Pizza' and then paginate that. All those examples just paginate without the where.  If I add that to the current SQL statement I end up just getting a few results.

Comment: I see.  The 4th and 5th links both address that.  Guess it doesn't matter now.  Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this article on codeproject 2-3 years ago when paging support is still fairly limited in the framework, perhaps still a good reference.

If you only concern about the data, just check out the section on how I retrieve paged data.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/GridViewNeatPaging.aspx